# share ssh public key on sftp configuration

Tags: ssh, centos, sftp, public-key

I've configured a SFTP server on CentOS following [this doc](https://www.vultr.com/docs/setup-sftp-only-user-accounts-on-centos-7). My intention is to forbid the console login for the new users (`user1`, `user2`), which belong to the `sftpusers` group, but still can log in to their respective `sftp` folders.

Also, I want to use the same keys used by the CentOS user (which can log in to console and `sftp` without problem). To do that, I copied the `.ssh` folder from CentOS user to the `user1` and `user2` home folders, changing ownership to the users and `700` for the `.ssh` folder and `600` for `authorized_keys` file.

Still, I keep receiving the message `Server refused our key`.  The key used by the CentOS user is like a master key in all servers, that is why I want to reuse that key for the new users.

How can I achieve this configuration?

> **UPDATE**

After generating keys for each user both users can access to server remotely with their privates keys but when I activate the following config in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` the permissions are denied using the `sftp` command.

> SSHD configuration

```
Match Group sftpusers #Or you could replace Group with User and specify a different configuration for each user
X11Forwarding no
AllowAgentForwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
ChrootDirectory /path/to/shared_folder/%u # %h the path to upload the files
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

> Message from shell

```
packet_write_wait: Connection to IPSERVER port 22: Broken pipe
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: What do you mean by console login? Local login as in "on the machine" or remote login using ssh to an interactive shell?

Comment: both of them, but mainly remote

Comment: I understand you copied things (like `authorized_keys`) inside the server. Users trying to log in from the outside obviously use their private keys stored outside the server. So do they use the same key actually? If they do (or going to), then what prevents `user1` to log in as `user2` or `centos`? Is such "commune" your goal? What if `user1` turns malicious and needs to be banned? Are you going to ban the common key? and give a new key to everyone else?

Comment: Already done and checked the users are login with ssh remotely. Read updated question please

Comment: The update introduces an issue different than the original question. It looks like the original issue is not a problem anymore. Am I right? If so, the old issue only obfuscates the question. The question should be [edit]ed and the old issue dropped completely. This includes changing the title.

Answer (score 1):

The update introduces an issue different than the original question. It looks like the original issue is not a problem anymore. I'm addressing the update.

The [manual](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#ChrootDirectory) reads:

> `ChrootDirectory`
>   Specifies the pathname of a directory to `chroot(2)` to after authentication. At session startup `sshd(8)` checks that all components of the pathname are root-owned directories which are not writable by any other user or group.

My tests indicate if this condition is not satisfied then one will get `Broken pipe` when trying to log in with `sftp`.

In your case the pathname is `/path/to/shared_folder/%u`. Note `%u` (after expansion) is *also* a component; therefore it should be "root-owned and not writable by any other user or group". You should fix the ownership and permissions. Then, obviously, the user will not be able to write to the directory. Whatever pathname you use with `ChrootDirectory`, the user will not be able to write to it (unless the user is root). In other words the user will not be able to write to `/` in the chrooted environment. To allow writing, you need a subdirectory. There are few ways to deal with this.

- Using home directories in a common chroot directory.

  The manual also states:

  > After the `chroot`, `sshd(8)` changes the working directory to the user's home directory.

  I assume home directories are like `/home/user1`, `/home/user2` etc. by default. This suggests the following scenario:

  1. Setup the server to chroot to `/path/to/shared_folder` (no `%u`):

     ```
     ChrootDirectory /path/to/shared_folder
     ```
  2. Replicate the relevant directory structure there (`/path/to/shared_folder/home/user1` etc.).
  3. Satisfy the condition for `path`, `to` and `shared_folder`.
  4. Make ownership and permissions of `home` like they are for the regular `/home`.
  5. Make ownership and permissions of directories inside `home` like they are for directories in `/home`.

  With this setup `sftp` will automatically place `user1` in `/path/to/shared_folder/home/user1` after authenticating, but they will see it as `/home/user1` due to `chroot`.
- Using custom directories in a common chroot directory.

  With `ForceCommand internal-sftp` you can specify the starting directory (`internal-sftp` supports the same set of options as [`sftp-server`](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp-server)). Like this:

  ```
  ChrootDirectory /path/to/shared_folder
  ForceCommand internal-sftp -d /home/%u
  ```

  to make sure `sftp` users will use `/path/to/shared_folder/home/…` regardless of their formal home directories in the OS. Or like this:

  ```
  ChrootDirectory /path/to/shared_folder
  ForceCommand internal-sftp -d /%u
  ```

  to simplify paths and get rid of this `home` in the middle. This way `user1` will see they are in `/user1` after logging in with `sftp`. In this case `shared_folder` should directly contain user folders (not `home`).
- Using at least one subdirectory in a chroot directory specific to the user.

  The solutions above allow users to browse each other's directories. A user will be able to `chmod` their files (`sftp` supports `chmod`) to grant or deny access.

  You used `%u` with `ChrootDirectory`, so you most likely want to create separate chroot directories. In such case do what you did:

  ```
  ChrootDirectory /path/to/shared_folder/%u
  ```

  and set ownership and permissions of every component (including what `%u` expands to) to satisfy the condition. Unless it's about read-only access, you need at least one subdirectory that will be writable by the user. Few possibilities:

  - replicating path to the user's home directory, as defined in the OS;
  - forcing `/home/%u` with `ForceCommand internal-sftp -d /home/%u`;
  - forcing `/%u` with `ForceCommand internal-sftp -d /%u`;
  - using a fixed subdirectory name, e.g. `ForceCommand internal-sftp -d /files`.

  In each case you need to prepare the directory structure inside `/path/to/shared_folder`. E.g. if you want to force `/home/user1` for `user1`, the relevant path will be:

  ```
  /path/to/shared_folder/user1/home/user1
  ```

  where `path`, `to`, `shared_folder` and (the first) `user1` satisfy the condition, `home` simulates `/home` and (the second) `user1` is writable by the user.

More flexible approaches are possible. E.g. you can have a common chroot directory for `user1` and `user2`, but different one for `user3`.

Chroot directory common or not, personally I would make the subdirectories in the least surprising fashion, so any user find themselves in a directory they kinda expect. After typing `pwd` in `sftp` they should see like `/home/user1`. I find other possibilities (`/user1`, `/files`) somewhat surprising.